# I am trying to find a specific struct member which a vector of structs using a lambda function

Tags: c++, vector, struct, lambda, compilation

I have been given the following struct. I have a vector of tps.

```
struct tp{
  unsigned int channel;
  unsigned int tstart;
  unsigned int tspan;
  unsigned int adcsum;
  unsigned int adcpeak;
  unsigned int flags;
};
```

I cannot modify the struct nor add an operator to it. I have a vector(all_candidates) of specific tstarts that i need to look for on the vector of tps.

```
std::vector< TP> Tps; //these are the input TPs.
std::vector< std::pair<double,double> > all_candidates;//every element is a time-tstart from a TP.

const auto& tmp1 = &(all_candidates.at[0].first);
auto first_tp = std::find_if(candidates.begin(),candidates.end(),[&tmp1](const TP& tp_1){return tp_1.first_time == tmp1 ;});
```

But when i run this code I get a compiling error, the first one being:

```
 error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    const auto& tmp1 = all_candidates.at[0].first;
```

what is the correct syntax to find the TPs given a start?
Thanks

Comment: Is it a typo? `all_candidates.at[0]` -> `all_candidates.at(0)`?

Comment: You define `struct tp` but have a `std::vector<TP>`. What's the relation between `tp` and `TP`? Any?

Comment: What is the pair in `all_candidates` representing? A `tstart` is an `int`, not a `std::pair<double, double>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error tells you, the line

```
const auto& tmp1 = &(all_candidates.at[0].first);
```

is the problem. As Algirdas Preidžius noted, it should be `all_candidates.at(0)`. Also, the second `&` is superfluous and is interpreted as an address operator. The line should be:

```
const auto& tmp1 = all_candidates.at(0).first;
```

However, since `tstart` is a simple `int`, there is no need for references here. You could simple write:

```
const int tmp1 = all_candidates.at(0).first;
```

Likewise, you can just capture `tmp1` by value instead of by reference in your lambda.

Comment: question, on this. How can i modify it to find the index where the corresponding candidate happens?

Comment: @IP25 `find_if` returns an iterator to the candidate. To get the index you can just use `first_tp - candiates.begin()`.